# Why can I only perform a mouseover action on a single page per test

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform move_to_element in the same test on 2 different page (without tearing down) and I am getting a `StaleElementException` thrown.
The test is basically an eCommerce website, I have to hover over a product in order to have the option of adding it to cart. On the homepage I have to hover over the menu in order to get to the product's category.

I'm attaching a function below (which is what I use). It handles a situation where there is a popup and then exits it and tries again.

```
 @staticmethod
def hover_over(some_element):
    try:
        action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((some_element)))).perform()
    except WebDriverException:
        try:
            pop = browser.find_element(*popup_exit_class)
            pop.click()
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((some_element)))
            action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((some_element)))).perform()
```

I have also tried without the function:

```
 x = browser.find_element(*some_element)
    action.move_to_element(x).perform()
    sleep(0.5)
    browser.find_element(*some_other_element).click()
```

If it's any help I'm using Chromedriver (It also occurs on Firefox) on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

A web element is attached to a page. If the page is reloaded, then your element is deleted and a new one is created. This is why you are getting the `StaleElementException` exception. Moreover you need to instantiate the ActionChains for each call:

```
some_element = (By.ID, "...")

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(some_element))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()

browser.find_element(*popup_exit_class).click()

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(some_element))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I AM using a locator. Forgot to mention, I have a locators.py file where every element I pass to a function exists in form of (By.method, "selector_or_whatever"). For example: func.hover_over(header.mini_cart) where header.mini_cart is mini_cart = (By.ID, "cartHeader")

Comment: I haven't noticed at first, but you also need to instantiate the `ActionChains `for each `perform`.